# Are there any measures of U-6 Unemployment that take into account ageing out of the work force explicitly?

Tags: labor-economics, data-request, statistics, unemployment

Labor Force Participation has been [steadily decreasing over the last 20 years or so](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CIVPART). The Fed says that this has been the case mostly due to the [demographic shifts](https://research.stlouisfed.org/publications/page1-econ/2016/02/01/making-sense-of-unemployment-data/?&utm_source=fred.stlouisfed.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_term=related_resources&utm_content=&utm_campaign=pageone), and to an extent the data backs that up. But I can't find anything specifically showing this effect. Is the data set used to create this information publicly available and/or is there information on U-6 measured  specifically for ages 25-54?

Comment: Search on FRED or on the BLS page. There are measures for more refined age cohorts. One issue is that the samples get smaller, but if you are looking at general trends, that should not be an issue.